# Unexpected results testing serial loopback using echo and cat

Tags: cat, serial-port, echo

So I have a standard RS232 serial port that is looped back to itself by simply running a wire from Tx to Rx.  I'm testing loopback by running `echo` and `cat` in two separate terminals:

```
cat /dev/ttyS1
echo "hi" > /dev/ttyS1
```

My issue is with the output.  I would expect to see one "hi" come back on the terminal running cat but instead I get this:

```
hi
[2 newlines]
hi
[4 newlines]
hi
[8 newlines]
hi
[16 newlines]
hi
[32 newlines]
hi
```

...and so on until I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> `cat`.

After interrupting cat, if I run it again it will not output "hi"s until I run echo a second time.

Is this normal?  Any idea why I'm seeing this behavior?

**Edit**: By newline, I mean ASCII `0x0A`.  There are no carriage returns in this output.

Comment: Could it be caused by having two processes opening the same device? What if you run `tip /dev/ttyS1` (`~.` to exit) and tried typing data there? It should be displayed in your terminal when the wire is connected, as it receives what it has transmitted.

Comment: Are you *really* getting newlines, or a carriage-return/newline pair? The distinction is important at the level you're working. Try "cat /dev/ttyS1 > somefile" then do "od -x somefile" to see exactly what bytes are coming out of the TTY device file.  Also, do an "stty -F /dev/ttyS1 -a".  Read the man page for "stty" and look at what the output of stty tells you, for every little setting. RS232 serial comms are tricky.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to the second comment by Bruce, I was able to figure out the problem on my own.

After running `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS1`, there were 3 options I found to contribute to the problem: "echo", "onlcr", and "icrnl".

Since this serial port is looped back to itself, here is what happened after running `echo "hi" > /dev/ttyS1`:

1. The `echo` command appends a newline to the end of the message by default, so "hi" + LF is sent out to /dev/ttyS1
2. Because "onlcr" was set, the serial device converted the LF to CRLF so the physical message sent out the Tx line was "hi" + CRLF
3. Because "icrnl" was set, the physical messaged received on the Rx line converted the CR to LF.  So the message outputted by 'cat' was "hi" + LFLF.
4. Because "echo" was set, the message received on the Rx ("hi" + LFLF), was then sent back out on the Tx line.
5. Because of onlcr, "hi" + LFLF became "hi" + CRLFCRLF.
6. Because of icrnl, "hi" + CRLFCRLF became "hi" + LFLFLFLF
7. Because of echo, "hi" + LFLFLFLF was then sent out the Tx

And so on...

In order to fix this problem, I ran the following command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 -echo -onlcr
```

Disabling "echo" prevents an infinite loop of messages and disabling "onlcr" prevents the serial device from converting LF to CRLF on output.  Now `cat` receives one "hi" (with a single newline!) for each time I run `echo`.

*CR = carriage return (ASCII 0x0D); LF = line feed or newline (ASCII 0x0A)*

Comment: `-icrnl` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue as well with concatenating files into a serial tty for testing. In addition to the accepted answer:

If you're testing serial output by doing something like: `cat somefile.txt > /dev/ttyS0`, it will have a good amount of unexpected byte data if you're testing for exact byte values.

With `stty` doing a simple `stty raw -F /dev/ttyS0` will stop the terminal from inserting/replacing characters (e.g. `[...] 0x0A [...]` -> `[...] 0x0D 0x0A [...]`). The `raw` flag changes the modes of the terminal so no input and output processing is performed.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't look like `stty raw` will disable echoing by default.  You may need to do `stty raw -echo`.

Comment: `sudo stty raw -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -echo` fixed it for me.