# Why changing tty settings on one file descriptor affects another?

Tags: tty, file-descriptors, pty, stty

`ECHO` setting is enabled on stdin and stdout by default.
But why if we disable `ECHO` on stdin, it is also disabled on `stdout`?
They have two separate descriptors - `0` and `1`, so why they are changed simultaneously as if they had one and the same file descriptor?

The following program demonstrates this:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct termios tty_stdin;
  struct termios tty_stdin_restore;
  struct termios tty_stdout;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty_stdin);
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty_stdin_restore);

  /* disable echo on stdin */
  tty_stdin.c_lflag &= (tcflag_t) ~ECHO;
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_stdin);

  /* observe that it was automatically disabled on stdout */
  tcgetattr(STDOUT_FILENO, &tty_stdout);
  printf("STDOUT ECHO after changing STDIN: %d\n", tty_stdout.c_lflag & ECHO ? 1 : 0);

  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_stdin_restore);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running your program with stdin or stdout redirected, or both redirected but not to the same tty. Then try opening two fd's on the same disk file and see what happens if you `write` one and `read` the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing attributes of the device, not the file descriptor. The file descriptor is just a way of identifying which device you're talking about. If both stdin and stdout are the same tty (`/dev/pts/0` for example) then it doesn't matter which one you use for `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr`.

Since echoing by definition involves input and output, it's hard to imagine what it might mean for echoing to be enabled on input and not output, or vice versa. Either the tty driver will echo, or it won't. Did you have a goal in mind that involves modifying the echo behavior in some way? If so, say what you're trying to accomplish and maybe someone will know how to do it properly.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to direct input from keyboard to serial port, and direct output from serial port to my monitor. I'm trying to understand exact path which the data is travelling. Also I do not understand from where comes "echo feedback loop" effect. (I have RX and TX of my com port connected directly)

Comment: Do I have this path? `terminal -> /dev/pts/0 -> program -> /dev/ttyS0` So, there are actually **two** TTYs in the path, not one? So, how do I know on which one of the two TTYs settings must be made (baud, echo, canonical, etc)?

Comment: I don't know anything about what you are doing. The code you have shown didn't include opening any tty's, just operating on stdin and stdout, which are inherited from the parent process. There's no way I can tell where those file descriptors are pointing, and I also don't know what kind of serial device you have connected to your port.

Comment: The "echo feedback loop" problem is described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42964/, but I cannot understand the answer.

Comment: You're just trying to repeat the experiment of `cat /dev/ttyS0` and `echo hi > /dev/ttyS0` with a looped-back port? It seems like disabling echo is a good idea then. Maybe if you post a question with *all* of your code, including the commands you're running to set things up, it would be possible to see what's going on.